# Is it possible to add "keyed-subscripting" to Class objects?

Tags: objective-c, class, nsobject, metaclass, subscript

In the vein of...

```
@implementation MyClass
- (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)k { 
       return [self something:k]; 
}
```

Is it also possible to "subscript" `Class` objects?  I too, am about to find out, with you..  but thought I would post this question as I tested it out, myself...

```
+ (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)k { 
       return [self.shared something:k]; 
}
```

And alas.. it is not...

```
id x = MyClass[@"document"];
```

> error: unexpected interface name 'MyClass': expected expression

***But why, Daddy?***  `Class`' *sure get the short end* of `NSObject`'s stick, *if you ask me*.

Comment: I'd suggest create global pointer at shared instance if you don't want write long code `MyClass.shared[@"document"];`

Comment: You're using the _type name_. Try it with a class object in a variable. `id myClass = [MyClass class]; myClass[@"document"];` Or `[MyClass class][@"document"]`.

Comment: Okay, I just grasped why you think that should work -- the subscript is turned into a message send, and the class name is valid as the reciever of a message send. It wouldn't  surprise me, though, that the parser will only accept a _literal_ message send (or the dot syntax).

Comment: @Cy-4AH My current approach is to usually just create C functions that do roughly the same as you suggest.. `id MyClassReaper(NSString *str) {  return objc_msgSend(MyClass.class, NSSelectorFromString(str)); }`, etc...  Again, these examples are only illustrative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Josh Caswell's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440600/is-it-possible-to-add-keyed-subscripting-to-class-objects#comment35939398_23440600) pointed out the problem:

> You're using the *type name*. Try it with a class object in a variable. `id myClass = [MyClass class]; myClass[@"document"];` Or `[MyClass class][@"document"]`

*I SWEAR I had tried that*.  **BIBLE**.  But the proof is in the pudding...

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (readonly) id  boring;
@end
@implementation MyClass
- boring   { return @"typical"; }
+ document { return  @"YEEHAW"; }
- objectForKeyedSubscript:key { return [self valueForKey:key]; }
+ objectForKeyedSubscript:key { 
  return [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]; 
}
@end
```

...

```
id a = MyClass.new;
id x = a[@"boring"];   // "typical" (via "normal" keyed subscription)
id b = MyClass.class;
   x = z[@"document"]; // "YEEHAW" (via CLASS keyed-subscript!)
```

or for all my *one-liner [freaky-deaky's](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=freaky%20deaky)* out there...

```
x = ((id)MyClass.class)[@"document"] // "YEEHAW"
```

Comment: +1 to both question and answer for humorous language interspersed with concise writing.

Comment: I believe by `z` you meant `b`, or vice versa.