# Class-level objectForKeyedSubscript:

Tags: objective-c, class-method, objective-c-literals

I get an error when I use `objectForKeyedSubscript:` as a class level method, so in my class "MyExample.h/.m" I have something like the following:

```
+ (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString*)key;
```

and I want to do `MyExample[@"key"]`, I initialize a static dictionary in a class method.

Are `objectForKeyedSubscript:` and the brackets meant to only be used with objects? Is there an alternative way to do it on a class level?

Comment: Your intuition that this should work is correct; classes _are_ objects in ObjC. They are instances of their "metaclass".

Comment: Yup. I just noticed the other question (didn't come up in my search). Do you know what @Cy-4AH means in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440600/is-it-possible-to-add-keyed-subscripting-to-class-objects#comment35943055_23440600

Comment: I think e's talking about something like this: [Global variables for class methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8498798/). Or maybe just your [basic ObjC "singleton"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like).